# How do you get the frontend URL from the backend in typo3?

Tags: typo3

How do I get the the frontend URL when a page is opened from the backend instead of the default index.php URL

e.g

Backend URL:
https://backend.website.com/index.php?id=22243

Frontend URL:
https://website.com/cat/mypage

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::getPreviewUrl($pageId);`

Comment: Thanks George. I don't have access to BackendUtility.php. My access is very limited.

Comment: if you are only editor you can click the preview icon to open the frontend in a new tab and get the URL from there

Answer (score 0):

Which version of TYPO3 do you use? With TYPO3 9.5, the new frontend routing has been introduced. You should have a field "URL Segment" in your page properties:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

---

You can try by writing the path name in the url.

Then it should work also.

Comment: I'm trying to find the front end url in the backend. I don't know the frontend url path.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.